# How to use PostgreSQL json_array_elements whit WHERE <value> IN clause

Tags: json, postgresql

I have `occasion` and `relation` tables. `relation.occasions` is a json type field, which contains an array of occasion keys. I want to get `occasion` records by relation, where `occasion.key` in `relation.occasions`. Assume, that this is my DB data:

**occasion**

```
        key      |     name      |
-------------------------------------
    BIRTHDAY     |   Birthday    |
    ANNIVERSARY  |   Anniversary |
```

**relation**

```
    key          | occasions                         |
------------------------------------------------------
    FATHER       |   [ "BIRTHDAY", "ANNIVERSARY" ]   |
    FRIEND       |   [ "BIRTHDAY" ]                  |
```

Here is the query I'm trying to use:

```
SELECT * FROM occasion o WHERE o.key IN
(SELECT json_array_elements(r.occasions)::text from relation r WHERE r.key = 'FATHER')
```

The result is 0 rows instead of expected 2. Can somebody give me a hint what am I doing wrong? How else can I achieve desired result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `json_array_elements()` returns a set, not an array, so you should use it as a row source, not in the select list.

The correct query would be:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM occasion o
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT j.value
    FROM relation
    JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements_text(occasions) j(value) ON true
    WHERE key = 'FATHER') sub ON o.key = sub.value;
```

You can also flatten it out without the sub-query, but I find this version to be more readable (the query planner will do the flattening anyway).

Comment: `select o.* from occasion o join relation r on (o.key = any(select json_array_elements_text(r.occasions)) and r.key = 'FATHER');` - simpler a bit, but assuming that te keys is unique.

Comment: @Abelisto Using a SRF in a select list should be avoided: [They are used like a table, view, or subquery in the FROM clause of a query.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS)

Comment: Your link is exactly about `FROM` clause, not about SRF usage. [Set Returning Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-srf.html), example from the official documentation: `SELECT generate_series(1.1, 4, 1.3);`

Comment: @Abelisto The documentation is certainly far from perfect on this issue, but that doesn't make your suggestion right. Any function that returns a set of rows is by definition a SRF (or table function, or row source) and should thus be used in the `FROM` clause. The simple reason for that is consistency and predictability. For instance, with a table `a` with 5 rows, how many rows do you get with `SELECT a.*, generate_series(1, 5) FROM a`?

Comment: 25 obviously. I really can not understand why do you think that it is not "consistent and predictable". BTW, C++ also hard to understand for many, but it is not the reason to say "using C++ should be avoided".

Comment: `SELECT a.*, generate_series(1, 5) as n FROM a` is same to `SELECT a.*, s.n FROM a cross join generate_series(1, 5) as s(n);` IMO the result is absolutely obvious. However our discussion is about personal opinion, not about technical details.